# Understanding binary conversions

Tags: c++, binary, binaryfiles

I'm writing a resource file which I want to insert a bunch of data from various common files such as .JPG, .BMP (for example) and I want it to be in binary.
I'm going to code something to retrieve these data later on organized by index, and this is what I got so far:

```
float randomValue = 23.14f;

ofstream fileWriter;
fileWriter.open("myFile.dat", ios::binary);
fileWriter.write((char*)&randomValue, sizeof(randomValue));
fileWriter.close();
//With this my .dat file, when opened in notepad has "B!¹A" in it

float retrieveValue = 0.0f;

ifstream fileReader;
fileReader.open("myFile.dat", ios::binary);
fileReader.read((char*)&retrieveValue, sizeof(retrieveValue));
fileReader.close();

cout << retrieveValue << endl; //This gives me exactly the 23.14 I wanted, perfect!
```

While this works nicely, I'd like to understand what exactly is happening there.
I'm converting the address of *randomValue* to char*, and writing the values in this address to the file?

I'm curious also because I need to do this for an array, and I can't do this:

```
int* myArray = new int[10];
//fill myArray values with random stuff

fileWriter.open("myFile.dat", ios::binary);
fileWriter.write((char*)&myArray, sizeof(myArray));
fileWriter.close();
```

From what I understand, this would just write the first address' value in the file, not all the array. So, for testing, I'm trying to simply convert a variable to a char* which I would write to a file, and convert back to the variable to see if I'm retrieving the values correctly, so I'm with this:

```
int* intArray = new int[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << &intArray[i]; //the address of each number in my array
    cout << intArray[i]; //it's value
    cout << reinterpret_cast<char*>(&intArray[i]); //the char* value of each one     
}
```

But for some reason I don't know, my computer "beeps" when I run this code. During the array, I'm also saving these to a char* and trying to convert back to int, but I'm not getting the results expected, I'm getting some really long values.
Something like:

```
float randomValue = 23.14f;

char* charValue = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&randomValue);
//charValue contains "B!¹A" plus a bunch of other (un-initiallized values?) characters, so I'm guessing the value is correct

//Now I'm here
```

I want to convert charValue back to randomValue, how can I do it?

**edit**: There's valuable information in the answers below, but they don't solve my (original) problem. I was testing these type of conversions because I'm doing a code that I will pick a bunch of resource files such as BMP, JPG, MP3, and save them in a single .DAT file organized by some criteria I still haven't fully figured out.

Later, I am going to use this resource file to read from and load these contents into a program (game) I'm coding.

The criteria I am still thinking but I was wondering if it's possible to do something like this:

```
//In my ResourceFile.DAT
[4 bytes = objectID][3 bytes = objectType (WAV, MP3, JPG, BMP, etc)][4 bytes = objectLength][objectLength bytes = actual objectData]
//repeating this until end of file
```

And then in the code that reads the resource file, I want to do something like this (untested):

```
ifstream fileReader;
fileReader.open("myFile.DAT", ios::binary);
//file check stuff
while(!fileReader.eof())
{
    //Here I'll load
    int objectID = 0;
    fileReader((char*)&objectID, 4); //read 4 bytes to fill objectID

    char objectType[3];
    fileReader(&objectType, 3); //read the type so I know which parser use

    int objectLength = 0;
    fileReader((char*)&objectLength, 4); //get the length of the object data

    char* objectData = new char[objectLength];
    fileReader(objectData, objectLength); //fill objectData with the data

    //Here I'll use a parser to fill classes depending on the type etc, and move on to the next obj
}
```

Currently my code is working with the original files (BMP, WAV, etc) and filling them into classes, and I want to know how I can save the data from these files into a binary data file.
For example, my class that manages BMP data has this:

```
class FileBMP
{
    public:
        int imageWidth;
        int imageHeight;
        int* imageData;
}
```

When I load it, I call:

```
void FileBMP::Load(int iwidth, int iheight)
{
    int imageTotalSize = iwidth * iheight * 4;
    imageData = new int[imageTotalSize]; //This will give me 4 times the amount of pixels in the image

    int cPixel = 0;
    while(cPixel < imageTotalSize)
    {
        imageData[cPixel] = 0;     //R value
        imageData[cPixel + 1] = 0; //G value
        imageData[cPixel + 2] = 0; //B value
        imageData[cPixel + 3] = 0; //A value
        cPixel += 4;
    }
}
```

So I have this single dimension array containing values in the format of [RGBA] per pixel, which I am using later on for drawing on screen.
I want to be able to save just this array in the binary data format that I am planning that I stated above, and then read it and fill this array.

I think it's asking too much for a code like this, so I'd like to understand what I need to know to save these values into a binary file and then read back to fill it.

Sorry for the long post!

**edit2:** I solved my problem by making the first edit... thanks for the valuable info, I also got to know what I wanted to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the & operator, you're getting a pointer to the contents of the variable (think of it as just a memory address).

```
float a = 123.45f;
float* p = &a; // now p points to a, i.e. has the memory address to a's contents.
char* c = (char*)&a; // c points to the same memory location, but the code says to treat the contents as char instead of float.
```

When you gave the (char*)&randomValue for write(), you simply told "take this memory address having char data and write sizeof(randomValue) chars from there". You're not writing the address value itself, but the contents from that location of memory ("raw binary data").

```
cout << reinterpret_cast<char*>(&intArray[i]); //the char* value of each one
```

Here you're expected to give char* type data, terminated with a null char (zero). However, you're providing the raw bytes of the float value instead. Your program might crash here, as cout will input chars until it finds the terminator char -- which it might not find anytime soon.

```
float randomValue = 23.14f;
char* charValue = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&randomValue);

float back = *(float*)charValue;
```

Edit: to save binary data, you simply need to provide the data and write() it. Do not use << operator overloads with ofstream/cout. For example:

```
    int values[3] = { 5, 6, 7 };
struct AnyData
{
   float a;
   int b;
} data;

cout.write((char*)&values, sizeof(int) * 3); // the other two values follow the first one, you can write them all at once.
cout.write((char*)&data, sizeof(data)); // you can also save structs that do not have pointers.
```

In case you're going to write structs, have a look at *#pragma pack* compiler directive. Compilers will align (use padding) variable to certain size (int), which means that the following struct actually might require 8 bytes:

```
#pragma pack (push, 1)
struct CouldBeLongerThanYouThink
{
  char a;
  char b;
};
#pragma pack (pop)
```

Also, do not write pointer values itself (if there are pointer members in a struct), because the memory addresses will not point to any meaningful data once read back from a file. Always write the data itself, not pointer values.

Comment: Oh, that's why I was getting the invalid access memory errors... the first block of code though, doesn't it have any trouble with unspecified bytes? float is 4 bytes, char is 1 byte, what happens to the other 3 bytes when I say to treat it as a char*? (I don't want to lose information when converting and saving to the file)

Comment: When you tell write() to write 4 chars, it will attempt to do so regardless of where the pointer points to or what type the data actually is. Same goes for read(). C++ does not _really_ care how many bytes or what type you actually have, char* just tells that there should be one char where the pointer points to. You also should not trust that char is single byte, even though if almost always is. Some read/write functions take void* input and number of bytes as parameters (unlike the fstream methods, which want chars).

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that you're copying the internal
representation of your data to a file, and then copying it back
into memory,  This works as long as the program doing the
writing was compiled with the same version of the compiler,
using the same options.  Otherwise, it might or it might not
work, depending on any number of things beyond your control.

It's not clear to me what you're trying to do, but formats like
.jpg and .bmp normally specify the format they want the 
different types to have, and you have to respect that format.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you really want to do, so I cannot recommend a way of solving your real problem. But I would not be surprised if running the program actually caused beeps or any other strange behavior in your program.

```
int* intArray = new int[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << reinterpret_cast<char*>(&intArray[i]);
}
```

The memory returned by `new` above is uninitialized, but you are trying to *print* it as if it was a null terminated string. That uninitialized memory could have the bell character (that causes beeps when *printed* to the terminal) or any other values, including that it might potentially not have a null termination and the insertion operator into the stream will overrun the buffer until it either finds a null or your program crashes accessing invalid memory.

There are other incorrect assumptions in your code, like for example given `int *p = new int[10];` the expression `sizeof(p)` will be the size of a pointer in your architecture, not 10 times the size of an integer.